# Simple neural net in python not working, problem with backpropagation algorithm perhaps?

Tags: python, backpropagation

I have made a small neural network that takes two inputs x,y and outputs z, a 1 or 0. There is one hidden layer with two neurons, h1,h2 and one neuron in the output layer. The inputs are height and width, integers between 0 and 100 and the classes are big and small (eg 10,8 is 'small' and 76,92 is 'big). There are linear and non linear datatypes. I have used the sigmoid activation function and am back-propagating with partial differentiation with respect to the weights and biases. I'm not using any Ml libraries. I'm trying to code in most of the maths directly. I can not get it to work. Perhaps I have made a mistake in the backpropagation algorithm as this was the most challenging part. I am hoping someone can point out what I've done wrong. Below is the code:

```
import random, numpy, math


lr = 1 #learning rate
dt = '1' #data type
epochs = 100000
tda = 50 #training data amount


def step(x): #step function
  if x > 0:
    x = 1
  else:
    x = 0
  return x

def error(truth, output):
  return 0.5 * (truth - output)**2

def sig(x): #sigmoid activation
  return 1/(1+numpy.exp(-x))


#weights
w = [random.random(),random.random(),random.random(),random.random(),random.random(),random.random()]


biases
b = [random.random(),random.random(),random.random()]



def Net(x, y, t) : # t is truth (or target)


  h1 = x*w[0]+y*w[1]+b[0] #summation in h1, first neuron in hidden layer
  h1out = sig(h1) #sigmoid activation


  h2 = x*w[2]+y*w[3]+b[1]
  h2out = sig(h2) 


  z = h1out*w[4]+h2out*w[5]+b[2] #z is output neuron
  zout = sig(z)

  e = error(t, zout) # e is error



  #backpropagation, partial differentiations to find error at each weight and bias
  e5 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * h1out #e5 is error at 5th weight etc
  e6 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * h2out

  e1 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[4] * (h1out * (1 - h1out)) * x
  e2 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[4] * (h1out * (1 - h1out)) * y
  e3 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[5] * (h2out * (1 - h2out)) * x
  e4 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[5] * (h2out * (1 - h2out)) * y


  be3 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) error at 3rd bias etc
  be1 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[4] * (h1out * (1 - h1out)) 
  be2 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[5] * (h2out * (1 - h2out)) 

  #print (e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, be1, be2, be3)

  #updating weights and biases
  w[0] = w[0] - (e1 * lr)
  w[1] = w[1] - (e2 * lr)
  w[2] = w[2] - (e3 * lr)
  w[3] = w[3] - (e4 * lr)

  w[4] = w[4] - (e5 * lr)
  w[5] = w[5] - (e6 * lr)


  b[2] = b[2] - (be3 * lr)

  b[0] = b[0] - (be1 * lr)
  b[1] = b[1] - (be2 * lr)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you have a classification task right? and your loss function ist MSE right?

Comment: its a binary classifier. the loss function is MSE yes:
def error(truth, output):
  return 0.5 * (truth - output)**2

Comment: Technically the output of MSE network is regression and not classification. you have to use crossentropy as loss function to be able to do classification.

Comment: check this [link](https://peltarion.com/knowledge-center/documentation/modeling-view/build-an-ai-model/loss-functions/binary-crossentropy) for the mathematics of it

Comment: ok thanks. I will try replacing MSE function with cross entropy loss function

Comment: I am still getting wrong results. the results appear to be "mirror images" of the correct, ie on a plot, the decision boundary is perpendicular to the true boundary

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzanf.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA8Zs.png
here are two images of plots to show what i mean

Comment: can you explain how you calculate the errors. I don't see any derivative of your activation fuctions in that calculation. or am I missing something?

Comment: i have changed partial differentiations to calculate the errors in the weights and biases, in the code labelled e1 to e6 and be1 to be3.
The sigmoid activation derivatives are (zout * (1 - zout)), (h1out * (1 - h1out)) and (h2out * (1 - h2out)), I think, maybe this is where Ive gone wrong.

(I think this net should be similar to one which solves the XOR problem, incase that makes it clearer what Im trying to do)

Comment: make sure your calculation od errors looks like the equations I postet as answer. you have to have 5 error (for each neuron) and be able 6 corrections (for every weight) using the derivative of the activation functions of every layer.

Comment: i scaled down to the input values to be between 0 and 1, rather than leaving them as between 0 and 100, and the net works now. maybe an example of failing to preprocess the input data? 
Thanks for the help. Why do you say 5 error for each neuron? I thought it was just 3 . 2 weights for inputs and 1 bias

Comment: normalization is ofcourse very important cause otherwise it can result unstability in the network. well actually you are using 3 times the activation function. 2 times for hidden neurons and one time for the classifier. so first you use the drivative of the functions to calculate the error caused by this specific neuron. then you use this to correct the weights connected to this neuron. I really recommend reading the backpropagation equations carefully cause everything I said could be understood was easier there. (btw upvotes would be nice if it was helpful)

Answer (score 0):

your backpropagation should look like this:

[image]

and that continues to less deeper layers. so you have to basically calculate the error of every neuron through the derivative of it's activation function. and use it for the error of previous layers.

[image]